# Update the whole structure

Tags: struct, scheme, set, racket, assign

Suppose I have some function which returns a struct:

```
(struct layer (points lines areas))

(define (build-new-layer height)
  ...
  (layer list-a list-b list-c))
```

I want to keep track of the last returned result something like:

```
(define top-side (build-new-layer 0)) ; store the first result
...
(set! top-side (build-new-layer 0.5)) ; throw away the first result and store the new one
```

However, for that particular code I get the error:

```
set!: assignment disallowed;
 cannot modify a constant
  constant: top-side
```

Please, tell me what would be the right way to do what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language are you using? it seems it's a matter of configuration, because in principle what you're doing should work. Go to the "choose language" window (Ctrl+L in Windows), click on "show details" and see if one of the options of the language currently in use disallows redefinition of variables. Alternatively, try using a different language.

Depending on *where* exactly you're going to use the stored result (I can't tell from the code in the question), you could pass it around as function parameters, in such a way that using a global variable is no longer necessary. This might be a better idea, relying on global state and mutation (the `set!` operation) is discouraged in Scheme.

Comment: If the user is doing a `set!` at the REPL, it's possible that it won't work if the definition is in a module.  Racket does a pass through a module's body to figure out what bindings are constant, and if the module's body itself doesn't `set!` the binding, it won't allow the REPL to `set!` it either.  See: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._compile-enforce-module-constants)).

Comment: If this is the case, then the user can add the following right below the first definition of `top-side`: `(set! top-side top-side)`.  It looks like a no-op, but it convinces Racket that `top-side` should not be treated as a module-bound constant.

Comment: Thanks, dyoo. `(set! top-side top-side)` really solved the issue. Unfortunately, I didn't find any useful information in the language window.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to keep around the last layer, then you might prefer setting the last-layer every time one is built.  Like this.

```
(define last-layer #f)
(define build-new-layer
  (let ((save-layer #f))
    (lambda (height)
      (let ((new-layer (layer list-a ...)))
        (set! last-layer save-layer)
        (set! save-layer new-layer)
        new-layer))))
```

Note: if the real problem is the 'constant-ness' of `last-layer` then build yourself a little abstraction as:

```
(define-values (last-layer-get last-layer-set!)
  (begin
    (define last-layer-access
      (let ((last-layer #f))
        (lambda (type . layer)
          (case type
           ((get) last-layer)
           ((set) (set! last-layer (car layer)))))))
    (values (lambda () (last-layer-access 'get))
            (lambda (layer) (last-layer-access 'set layer))))
```