# Differing behavior between debug and REPL mode in Dr. Racket: modifying a constant

Tags: debugging, scheme, racket

I am trying to code my own unit-test library in scheme. So far, I have the following code in the definition window:

```
#lang scheme
(define all-tests '())

(define-syntax make-tests
  (syntax-rules (->)
    [(_ test-name function (args ... -> result) ...)
     (begin
       (define test-name
         (list function (list (list args ...) ...) (list result ...)))
       (set! all-tests (cons test-name all-tests)))]))
```

Using Dr. Racket, when I submit the following code into the REPL:

```
> (make-tests tests + (1 2 -> 3))
set!: assignment disallowed;
 cannot modify a constant
  constant: all-tests
```

However when I tried to debug it in Dr. Racket:

```
(debug)> (make-tests tests + (1 2 -> 3))

(debug)> tests
(#<procedure:+> ((1 2)) (3))
(debug)> all-tests
((#<procedure:+> ((1 2)) (3)))
```

So, for some reason, in Dr. Racket v6.1, my code works in debug mode, but does not work when using the REPL. What is going on, and how can I debug my code?

Comment: This is just an aside, but the `#lang scheme` language setting is considered deprecated these days. You may be better off using `#lang racket` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment on [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15255312/1565698):  If a module doesn't mutate a binding you cannot mutate it from outside the module. Running code in the REPL is not the same as running code in the module. A racket source in Racket language is a module and `#lang scheme` is *not Scheme* but synonym for `#lang racket`.

So to get the behaviour you would like you can replace `(define all-tests '())` with:

```
(define all-tests #f)
(set! all-tests '())   ; quick fix that makes all-test mutable
```

And it will work. You may dig deeper into [racket documentation about it](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._compile-enforce-module-constants%29%29) too.

Answer (score 1):

You can Un-check the option `Enforce constant definition` In the choose language menu in DrRacket In the Dynamic properties box.

And as a note to your macro. Why do you specify a name for the test? The name is not placed in the list, and aside from defining it to cons it to `all-tests` it is never used. You can use a let instead. Unless of course your are going to do something with `tests` later.

```
(define-syntax make-tests
  (syntax-rules (->)
    [(_ function (args ... -> result) ...)
       (let
        ((test (list function (list (list args ...) ...) (list result ...))))
         (set! all-tests (cons test all-tests)))]))
```